# Adding a formula dynamically to an excel cell

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

Is there a way (VB?) to **add a formula dynamically to an excel cell**?

I have a cell with conditions true and false, and they change based on a checkbox.

And I have another cell, which has a formula in it. **This formula should be used if the checkbox is unchecked**. 
If the checkbox is **checked, then user should be able insert value** manually (without any formula prompting there).So the formula should not be there.

I was thinking of a solution where I would add the formula to the cell if checkbox is unchecked, and then if the checkbox is checked, then I would clear the cell.

How could this be done? I'm not very familiar with excel coding and VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a classical Excel CheckBox, you can **add a Linked Cell** which will be True or False.

In the following code, your **Linked Cell** is in `A1`, the **cell with the formula to use** in `B1` and the **cell that need to be empty or filled** by formula is in `C1`.

You'll need to **specify the Sheet_Name** (can be differents) and place that code directly into the **Sheet "module"** in VBA (press `Alt+F11` and double-click on the sheet (in the left panel) with the Linked Cell, then just paste and edit regarding your specifications)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LinkedCell As Range, _
    FormulaCell As Range, _
    ChangingCell As Range

Set LinkedCell = Sheets("Sheet_Name").Range("A1")
Set FormulaCell = Sheets("Sheet_Name").Range("B1")
Set ChangingCell = Sheets("Sheet_Name").Range("C1")


If Application.Intersect(Target, LinkedCell) Is Nothing Then
    'not in linked cell
Else
    'in linked cell
    If LinkedCell.Value2 <> True Then
        'Unchecked
        ChangingCell.FormulaLocal = ChangingCell.FormulaLocal
    Else
        'Checked
        ChangingCell.FormulaLocal = vbNullString
    End If
End If

Set LinkedCell = Nothing
Set FormulaCell = Nothing
Set ChangingCell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Problem is, that the sheets are created dynamically from the origin sheet, and then the name of the sheets are different. So if I would now put this code on the Sheet module, that is used as the base sheet for the generated sheets, then the name would be incorrect. I wonder if I could just choose the currently active sheet by ActiveSheet.Range, instead of Sheets("Sheet_Name").Range?

Comment: Yes you can, even if it is a bit risky as it might not be on the good one. Are the sheets'names impossible to anticipate? And this code must be put into a specific sheet, so worst scenario you create an empty sheet with the edited code regarding your constraints and copy it to have the code already in place with the new ones. Is your checkbox generated automatically too?

Comment: Yes, the new sheet's names are pretty easy to anticipate, it adds a running number to the sheet's name. The whole sheet is copied, including all the code and the checkbox. So the new generated sheet will have an excel object in VBA, with same code.

Comment: Ok so it will work nicely for you! Let me know if you have an issue with it! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by mixing your answer and other answer. I put your as correct since it was most clear, you put much effort on it and answered to comments, thanks!

Comment: Thx mate, glad you find the way to fix your issue! Good luck with the rest of your work!

Answer (score 2):

Ok you need a trigger on TRUE/FALSE cell to execut the next VBA code,
right click on sheet name and click "View Code" and enter this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A5")) Is Nothing Then 'define adress of your True/Flase cell
 If Target.Cells.Value = False then
 Range("B5").formula = "=enter your formula" 'define adress for cell with formula aswell
 else 
 Range("B5").value = ""
 end if
end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

well you could use:

```
if userform1.checkbox.checked = false then
range("A1").formula = "=myformula"
else
range("A1").value = ""
end if
```

you need to insert the code into the userform checkbox click or change event both should have same effect, just double click on the checkbox in userform and it will take you to the click event or replace the click with "change", hope that's what you meant to achieve, cheers
PS. thanks for suggestions @99moorem

Comment: I don't think that it is a UserForm mate